# WebDriver - maintaining web connection to retrieve textarea values

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textarea

I'm trying to get the values in the textarea field of an HTML page based on user input. The problem I have is, everytime I run the program, the API initiates a new connection to the webpage and reads the textarea value as empty. I've tried using JSOUP (which cannot do this) and as per recommendation, have switched to WebDriver. However, this also seems to give me empty values for the textarea field.

My question is, how do I keep getting updated values of textarea from the HTML page? The webpage in question is [HERE](http://aviprobo.doorfree.com/control.html). Everytime the user presses one of the buttons, the textarea prints a value corresponding to the button pressed. I want to be able to keep reading the textarea every so often (e.g; 0.5s which can be achieved using a thread).

The below is my WebDriver code;

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
String html = "http://aviprobo.doorfree.com/control.html";
driver.get(html);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("control"));
String text = element.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println ("text = " + text);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class TextArea

{

```
 public WebDriver driver;


    @Before
    public void setUp()

    {
        driver=new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
       ((HtmlUnitDriver) driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        driver.get("http://aviprobo.doorfree.com/control.html");


    }

    @Test
    public void testCase() 
   {

   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Up')]")).click();
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("control"));
   String text = element.getAttribute("value");
   System.out.println ("text = " + text);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Down')]")).click();
   text = element.getAttribute("value");
   System.out.println ("text = " + text);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Left')]")).click();
   text = element.getAttribute("value");
   System.out.println ("text = " + text);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Right')]")).click();
   text = element.getAttribute("value");
   System.out.println ("text = " + text);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Stop')]")).click();
   text = element.getAttribute("value");
   System.out.println ("text = " + text);
   }

   }
```

}

Comment: Just execute once you will know..his problem is solved  using above code

Comment: it is nothing to do with getText() or getAttribute()

Comment: actually, it turns out we were both right `:)`
https://gist.github.com/ddavison/8092890

Comment: Thanks kiran and sircapsalot! This solution is a good workaround for the problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

that's because a `<textarea>` element is a block level element.  Elements that are block level use the `innerHTML` property, not the `value` attribute.

Instead of getting the attribute, just return the text.

```
String text = driver.findElement(...).getText();
```

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rozln